# Execute a query 4 times with a loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I want to execute a query 4 times to insert data into a table. The variables `$answerformat` and `$feedbackformat` have a fixed value but the value for `$answer` and `$format` will change.

Here is what I have achieved so far:

```
 $answer=array('<p>ali<p>','<p>ali<p>','<p>ali<p>','<p>ali<p>');  
 $answerformat=1;
 $fraction=array('1.0000000','0.0000000','0.0000000','0.0000000');
 $feedbackformat=1;

 for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($answer);$i++){

 }
```

Comment: which value values will be inserted in database?

Comment: $answer,$answerformat,$fraction,$feedbackformat

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with the SQL syntax and PDO or mysqli, which are the MySQL interfaces of PHP, and insert an appropriate query. If it then does not work, we can help you. Also make sure to be informed about SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to put your query inside the loop. Have you tried reading about [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)?

Lets use `mysqli_*` extension as an example. We have to establish first a connection to your database, assuming that you have also established your user privileges, created a database, etc.:

```
$con = new mysqli("Host", "User", "Password", "Database"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY PARAMETERS INSIDE */

/* CHECK CONNECTION */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Then, lets proceed with your loop and insert query:

```
$answer = array('<p>ali<p>', '<p>ali<p>', '<p>ali<p>', '<p>ali<p>');  
$answerformat = 1;
$fraction = array('1.0000000', '0.0000000', '0.0000000', '0.0000000');
$feedbackformat = 1;

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($answer); $i++){

    /* PREPARE YOUR INSERT QUERY BELOW; REPLACE NECESSARY TABLE NAME AND COLUMN NAME; */
    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO yourTable (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $answer[$i], $answerformat, $fraction[$i], $feedbackformat); /* QUESTION MARKS IN YOUR INSERT QUERY WILL BE REPLACED WITH THESE FOUR VARIABLES; REPLACE OR REARRANGE PROPERLY THESE VARIABLES; s STANDS FOR STRINGS */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
    $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE PREPARED STATEMENT */

}
```

Have to remove `=` in your loop as it will loop five (5) times instead of four (4). Index of an array always starts with zero (0).